# I have an 03 Alero that won't start

Tags: starting, starter, oldsmobile, alero

I started the car and went to the store with no issue, less then an hour went to leave for work and got no response. Everything works fine I.e lights, radio, power windows, EXC. it just won't turn over. I assumed the starter went out on me.i took the starter off and had it tested. The starter turned over in the machine but the worker said it might be having trouble with the load but the new starter is expensive for me to just guess. I didn't get anything from the starter wile it was on the car" not even a click or tick". Is this a starter problem or something worse. Can anyone help me figure this out? With the info available would you replace the starter or continue trouble shooting?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did you also have the battery tested? Just because the lights, radio and windows work doesn't mean the battery is OK. Can you define **"got no response"**? Does it make any noise, like click?

Comment: Are you getting 12v to the starter when you turn the key?

Comment: I have no way to find that out

Comment: No clicks or ticks when I turn the key over

Comment: Maybe your battery is low. It takes more power to start a car than it does to turn on a radio...

Comment: Would a jump tell me if it's the battery? Example: if the starter won't turn over due to the bad battery could it start with a jump?

Comment: Sounds like a weak battery to me too. How old is the battery? It might be worth getting a multimeter to test the battery voltage.

Comment: I had the same problem. I turned the key to on position but do not start. Leave it there for 10 minutes turn off for 10 seconds. Try restarting car and hopefully it will start like mine did. (part of security system I was told).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me from your description as though either the relay is not telling the starter to energize or the ignition switch went bad. At this point I would not suspect the battery because you said you get nothing when you turn the key, but all of the accessories are working. You could have it tested just to eliminate it, but I'd not lean in the direction of it having an issue at this point. I don't think it's the starter, because you had it tested. If it isn't making any sort of noise, one might suspect the solenoid, but if the solenoid works when it's being bench tested, it's not the issue. Don't replace it (at this point) as this would cost you a lot of money for no reason.

You could possibly try to rotate the key several times in the ignition switch in rapid succession. If this causes the starter to kick at some point, this is where I'd start looking. If it does nothing, check to see if there's a starter relay in the under hood fuse box. If there, swap it out with a known good one (there should be several in this same location which don't need to be used to start the car). If the relay is bad, just replace it.

Other than that, you are probably looking at a trip to the mechanic. The reason for the issue is going to be buried somewhere in the wiring.

Comment: OK update, I have had the starter tested again and also had the battery checked for good measure, both checked out OK. Power is getting to the relay for the starter "in fuse box under the hood" because when the key is turned I can feel it clicking but still no response from the starter. I'm at a loss here I can assume the ignition went out I guess but I was told if I replace that the the car has to be reprogrammed so I am just beat on this one. Any additional advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to check to ensure the relay is passing power through it, not just going "click". The easiest way to do this is to exchange it with a known good one. You can also jump the through power (not the relay energizing circuit) to see if power is getting down to the starter.